# Convert dynamic disk to basic disk

Tags: windows

I accidentally converted my computer's disk to a dynamic disk. Since my system disk is a little bit small I want to install the system to another partition, but I got this error:

> Windows cannot be installed to this hard disk space; the partition contains one or more dynamic volumes that are not supported for installation.

It seems to suggest to convert the disk back to a basic disk, but to do that I have to delete the system volume which I can't do. How can I work around this? Can I use a USB live Linux to convert to a basic disk?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Live CD to redo this usually.  If not there is a way to switch it back with a Hex editor.

http://strangelyperfect.tv/6415/how-to-convert-a-dynamic-disk-to-basic-disk-in-windows-7/

Download the [Hex Editor here.](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)  Next

Open up your hex editor with admin rights. Go under Options and *turn off Read Only*.

Find Sector 0 Position 1C2 and verify that it is currently 42. Change from 42 to 07.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PartitionAssistant](http://www.partition-assistant.com/) for converting dynamic disk to basic. and [bootable version](http://www.partition-assistant.com/download/partition-assistant-iso-download.html)